# Opportunity ,contact and contracts or Quote

Tags: opportunity, quote

We need to send contract to our customer on some condition, but also we need to resend the same contract again or new version of the contract to the same customer(with new dates) if user is not signing it on time.

We are using opportunity to track the business. What would be the best way to send contract to customer?

1. Can I send multiple contract from one opportunity/ Contract?
2. Should i use quote instead of contract but we are not using products we just need to send contract after some approval and contract would valid for 1 year.

What process should I use to send multiple contract from same opportunity or contact and tract what contract we sent and report on it?

Should I create custom look-up field on "Contract" for "Contact or opportunity" to track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, there is no relation between Contract to Opportunity. You can create a lookup field (Opportunity) at Contract Object.

> 1- Can i send multiple contract from one opportunity/ Contract?

Yes, you can.

> 2- Should i use quote instead of contract but we are not using products we just need to send contract after some approval and contract would valid for 1 year.

Ideally, you can send a quote to customer and then after approval create a Contract for final signing from Customer. Some cases, customer might wants to see quotation before renewals.

Quote can have without products too.

You can setup business process with proper approvals.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions , but we dont have approval from customer , we are sending contract to get signed from customer , if customer signed it we need to create 3 days event for them. The process is that contract will send whenever opportunity is created than after sign we schedule a event for them to attend .

Comment: You can implement that business process then no need to create quote